# Can the Warforged Soldier reaction "Protection" be used for an attack targeting him?

Tags: dnd-5e, reactions, warforged

The *Protection* reaction on the *Warforged Soldier* Statblock states:

> *Protection*. When an attacker the warforged can see makes an attack roll against a creature within 5 feet of the warforged, the warforged can impose disadvantage on the attack roll.

So my thinking is as follows: The Warforged is within 5 feet of himself... thus if he is the target of an attack, he can use the reaction. I am not sure though if this is intended by the rules or if I'm thinking it right.

Would the *Warforged Soldier* be considered a creature within 5 feet of himself?